# What is the difference between String and String Buffer?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between String and StringBuffer in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439243/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-stringbuffer-in-java)

Hi

What is the difference between String and String Buffer? when shall i use each one?