# Different Between StringBuffer and String

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between String and StringBuffer in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439243/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-stringbuffer-in-java)

When I test a function using StringBuffer and String. When I use StringBuffer, I get the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError within the 2 or 3 secound.But, when I use String, I did not get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError error until one minutes. What different them, I don't know exactly.

```
public void print() {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    double result = 1.0 / 7.0;
    buffer.append(result);
    while (result != 0) {
        result = result % 7.0;
        buffer.append(result);
    }
    System.out.println(buffer.toString());
}


public void print() {
    String st = "";
    double result = 1.0 / 7.0;
    st = st + result;
    while (result != 0) {
        result = result % 7.0;
        st = st + result;
    }
    System.out.println(st);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439243/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-stringbuffer-in-java

Comment: It will be faster. I don't know why I get Out of Memory with StringBuffer. Now, I am taking reference in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439243/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-stringbuffer-in-java

Comment: `StringBuffer` is faster so you may run out of memory faster. You should check how many results got stored in each case to see if it's the problem with speed difference or the memory usage  difference between String and StringBuffer

Comment: I would add that `StringBuffer` was replaced in Java 5.0 eight years ago by `StringBuilder` but `String` is still used today.

Comment: [This](http://www.acquireandinspire.org/2013/01/string-string-builder-string-buffer.html) will make you understand the concepts clearly

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because when you use `StringBuffer`, your `while` loop executes 20 to 30 times faster than when you create new `String` at each iterations : as a consequence, you ran out of memory sooner.

BTW, never perform concatenation operations in a loop with String objects. Use `StringBuilder` instead (not `StringBuffer` as it is slightly slower than `StringBuilder` as its methods are `synchronized`).