# Differences between classes to work with text in Java String and StringBuffer

Tags: java

When I declare a `String` looks like:

```
String a= "Hello, World!"
```

What I would like to ask is: `String` makes from a an array?

Furthermore I understand that `StringBuffer` is special for text editing. If I use `String` the text cannot be changed while executing the program, that means that if I want to change or work with a text I should use `StringBuffer`.

Is that right guys?

Comment: `StringBuilder` is better than `StringBuffer`

Comment: StringBuilder? I should read about that. :)

Comment: You can read from here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: For more about the properties of `String` and other uses see http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/j3d_string.html

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera Better? I wouldn't say that. It depends on what you need ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between String and StringBuffer in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439243/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-stringbuffer-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

1. **Storage Area**
   1.1 `String` - Constant String Pool
   1.2 `StringBuffer` - Heap
   1.3 `StringBuilder` - Heap
2. **Modifiable**
   2.1 `String` - No (immutable)
   2.2 `StringBuffer` - Yes( mutable )
   2.3 `StringBuilder` - Yes( mutable )
3. **Thread Safe**
   3.1 `String` - Yes
   3.2 `StringBuffer` - Yes
   3.3 `StringBuilder` - No
4. **Performance**
   4.1 `String` - Fast
   4.2 `StringBuffer` - Very slow
   4.3 `StringBuilder` - Fast

Answer (score 0):

If **multiusers** are working at a String then better use `StringBuffer` (**Thread-safe**)

If only one user will be **editing** that String better use `StringBuilder` (Faster, Better Performance)

on the other side `String` is **immutable** which means if you are **NOT** planning to edit your String , you'd better go for Simple `String` object as it would be faster via caching

Answer (score 0):

Strings is immutable in java while the StringBuffer and StringBuilder classes are used when there is a necessity to make a lot of modifications to Strings of characters.

Unlike Strings objects of type StringBuffer and Stringbuilder can be modified over and over again with out leaving behind a lot of new unused objects.

The StringBuilder class was introduced as of Java 5 and the main difference between the StringBuffer and StringBuilder is that StringBuilders methods are not thread safe(not Synchronised).

It is recommended to use StringBuilder whenever possible because it is faster than StringBuffer. However if thread safety is necessary the best option is StringBuffer objects.
example

```
public class Test{

public static void main(String args[]){
   StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer(" test");
   sBuffer.append(" String Buffer");
   System.ou.println(sBuffer);  
   }
}
```

you can also use `delete(int start, int end), public insert(int offset, int i),replace(int start, int end, String str) functions with string builder and buffer class`

for more detail see this [link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/07/string-vs-stringbuffer-vs-stringbuilder.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
String a="Hello";
```

and you make `a=a+"World";`, then first string is "deleted", and you have a new string object(the object that a refer is changed). On the other hand, if you have

```
StringBuffer a=new StringBuffer("Hello");
```

and you `write a.append("world");`, a remains unchanged(same reference, only the state of the object has been changed, not the reference). Sorry for my english..

```
public class Puzzle {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String a = new String("Hello");
        String b = a;
        System.out.println(a == b); //it s true
        a = a + "world";
        System.out.println(a == b); //it s false

        StringBuffer c = new StringBuffer("Hello");
        StringBuffer d = c;
        System.out.println(c == d); //it s true
        c.append("world");
        System.out.println(c == d); //it s true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both to work with text but the main difference is that 'StringBuffer' is faster than 'String' when performing concatenations.

Answer (score 0):

hey you can change the value of a string

see example

```
String s="raju";
s=s+"ravi";
```

if we print `s` it will print

> raju ravi.

but `StringBuffer` is for thread safe when you are using `String` in multithreaded environment recommended to use `StringBuffer`.

If you want not immutable and not multithreaded environment and better performance should recommended to use `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

You can always change a String in java like:

```
String value = "hello";
value = value + " world";
System.out.println(value); // "hello world"
```

But this is computationally intensive, you should use StringBuilder instead:

```
StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder("hello");
value.append(" world");
System.out.println(value.toString()); // "hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

yes. If you want to store a string that is not going to change, you can use String datatype.
If you want a datatype which supports value modification, StringBuilder or StringBuffer are better than String.