# Difference between String , StringBuilder & StringBuffer?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I was just going through the net but I could not find a clear & precise

> difference between `String` ,`StringBuilder` & `StringBuffer` .
>
> Please also explain when should we use them and what do we mean by `thread-safe`
>   in java ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between String and StringBuffer in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439243/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-stringbuffer-in-java)

Comment: But I also want the different cases in which they can be used (which is not mentioned on that post).

Comment: possible duplicate of [String, StringBuffer, and StringBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971315/string-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder)

Comment: Use StringBuilder when you want to _build_ a _String_, and see Tagir Valeev's answer for why you don't want to use StringBuffer ever.  StringBuffer is obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will clarify the thread-safety point. The other points are well described in older questions.

It's quite rare case when `StringBuffer` suits your needs. While it's thread-safe it doesn't mean you will get what expected when using it from different threads. For example, suppose you have the following code:

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

public void appendMessage(String message) {
    buf.append("INFO: ").append(message).append(System.lineSeparator());
}
```

If you are using it in multithread environment it will not fail, but you may end up having content like this:

```
INFO: INFO: thread1 message
thread2 message
```

That's because individual `append` calls are synchronized, but the whole sequence is not.

In order to ensure that your messages are separately added, you must have an external synchronization like this:

```
Object lock = new Object();
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

public void appendMessage(String message) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        buf.append("INFO: ").append(message).append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
}
```

Here the whole sequence of calls is synchronized, so you will have the whole message appended at once. And as you are using the external synchronization, `StringBuilder` will work fine as well.

So in general `StringBuffer` should not be used in the most of situations.

Answer (score 1):

Main difference between String and StringBuilder/StringBuffer is that String is immutable, i.e. a String you once have initialized cannot be changed anymore. Redefining a String just creates a new immutable String in memory.
Instances of StringBuilder/StringBuffer can be modified by methods like append(String str) or insert(StringBuffer sb). The only difference between StringBuilder/StringBuffer is that StringBuilder is not safe for use by multiple threads, StringBuffer instead is thread-safe.

So if you want to use string objects that you define once and do not need to modify a lot, you use String. If you want to work on them you use StringBuilder, and if you want to do this in a multithreaded environment you use StringBuffer.