# How long strings can SPARQL handle?

Tags: sparql

I have the need to pass very long strings (such as full wikipedia pages) in SPARQL syntax, and thus was wondering if there is any theoretical and/or practical limits to how long strings can be handled in SPARQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only practical limit I'm aware of is that (historically) some web servers have had issues with long `GET` requests (that is, long URLs). For that reason you can typically [`POST` queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/#query-via-post-urlencoded) to the endpoint (despite the lack of side effects).

Other than that resources are, of course, finite and systems will have theoretical limits (e.g [How many characters can a Java String have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have)). Some systems will have performance issues with large literals, much like the database issue with varchars versus clobs.

Comment: Thanks, basically, that is what I needed to know! :)