# How many characters we can store in String datatype in java?

Tags: java, string

When we declare a variable with data type String in Java, how many characters can we store in  that variable?

For example, we write in code like:

```
String name;
```

This name variable is a string. So how many characters can we store in the variable `name`?

Comment: Check this out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little logic.

Java's string length  returns int, so Integer max value might be the max size.

Answer (score 0):

the boundary is `2^31-1 characters`, since the `getLength()`-method of String returns an int-value. The other boundary is your `RAM`. So your String is limited by the boundary that is reached first