# String's CharAt method using long

Tags: java

I want to find the character at a particular position of a very large string. However i am unable to use `charAt()` method because the range exceeds that of int. Is there a tweak to this?

Comment: Your string is over 2 billion characters long?

Comment: yeah.. I want to find character at position '2298867968'

Comment: probably best to break it up into smaller strings to begin with

Comment: So, when you print out the length of the `String`, it's a negative number?

Comment: The string generates itself based on that position value. For ex: if charAt(i)=='1' then the present character will be 2 etc. So I need to compare using charAt() function for larger values

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have for max string length

Comment: Then isnt my string even being created ?

Comment: If you're trying to create it, no it's probably not being created. Or not with the length you're expecting. Show how you're creating it, I guess.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Java, Strings are backed by a character array. The theoretical size of an array is limited by the maximum value of `int`, so it's impossible to have a String with over 2<sup>31</sup>-1 characters to begin with.

To overcome this issue you can create a string class of your own that uses multiple arrays or strings as storage.

Answer (score 0):

Would taking just a shorter substring from the large string and accessing the corresponding position help?

Comment: Nope,its a dynamically generating string based on a pre determined position. the position itself is out of integer scope.

Comment: Well but if you know that position, you can cut off the first x characters and then access the position minus x

Answer (score 0):

As the String is internally represented by array of chars its maximal length cannot be bigger than size of int. So in the first place you cannot have String that exceeds range of int.