# Is there any length limit for value kept in properties file?

Tags: java, limit, properties-file

I have `configAllowedUsers.properties`.

It has single in Entry like the following:

```
users = abc, pew, rt, me1, me3, ku3,........
```

I have some doubts about length of value stored in it. I will read it using  `java.util.Properties`. Thousands of usernames would be stored in it and I could not store them in database.

Comment: Just try it with a unit test :)

Answer (score 12):

I had the same question in mind today, so I started researching. I did not find any limitations originating from `java.util.Properties`, so it is probably safe to assume that the rules are the same as for `String`:

- A String of length [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) (which is 2<sup>31</sup>-1)
- Or [half your maximum heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1179996/3751577),

Whichever is reached first in your environment.

---

Of course, not finding any official statements on this topic does not prove that these assumptions are correct, but let's consider the `Properties` class *innocent unless proven guilty*.