# reducer with iterator error

Tags: java, hadoop, iterator, iterable

I have a reducer in hadoop with this code:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
/*some code*/
String followers = ""; 
  while(values.hasNext()){
        followers = followers + values.next().toString() + ",";
  }
/*some code*/
}
```

I want to make a list of followers for a certain node but when I run it I am getting this:

```
Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

If values is type Iterable then I don't have a problem but why is this happening?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I would guess that you're hitting the [max string length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have), but I can't tell without knowing how many values are in the iterator/ how big the values are

Comment: I am trying a very small input so I do not think I am hitting max string length.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a few side points: 1) You can do `followers += values...` 2) You can do `...values.next() + ",";`, since `toString()` is called implicitly 3) You should usually use a `StringBuilder` when concatenating strings in a loop.

Comment: thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're extending `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer` ([Java Docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html)) the method signature you've used for `reduce()` is incorrect. When you implement the `reduce()` method, you are overriding the implementation in the Reduce class.

You have:

`reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, Context context)`

It should be:

`reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)`

Note the difference between `Iterator` and `Iterable`. This probably means your reduce isnt actually being called.

You can add the `@Override` annotation to the method to help prevent this.

Comment: but when should I use iterator and when iterable in hadoop?

Comment: Your method signature must use Iterable, otherwise it wont actually get called.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand. We're talking about the method signature, that signature is fixed. If something is `Iterable` you can easily loop using `for (Text t : values) { }`. If you ever see `Iterator` in a reduce method signature, they've got it wrong.