# OrientDB query (string) length

Tags: sql, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I am using OrientDB 2.2.17.

I have 2 question regarding the query string sent to:

```
String query = "SELECT FROM XXX WHERE num IN[1,2,3,4]";
graph.command(new OCommandSQL(query));
```

1. What is the max length allowed in the string: 'query'?
2. If inside the 'query' string I use the operator "IN" - is there a limit for the number of the items inside the 'IN' list?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no technical limit, apart from:

- heap memory: a huge statement has to be parsed and the AST has to be stored in the heap
- Java limitations: a string cannot be longer than Integer.MAX_VALUE (see [How many characters can a Java String have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have)), same applies to the number of items in an array

This said, the query has to be parsed, so a lot query string will result in a slower parsing