# Maximum size to store in a String (the base64 of a file) - Java

Tags: java, string, base64

I have a file, then I convert it to base64 and finaly this base64 is stored into a String variable.

And the question is, what is the **maximum size of the file** that I can convert to base64 and **store** it in a String variable?

If anyone could help me.
Thank you in advance

(With Java of course...)

Comment: See also [How many characters can a Java String have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String`s can hold a lot of data* - I'd be more concerned about your available heap memory if you're putting a whole file into memory that way. Especially as you have to be careful not to have it in memory twice for the base64 conversion...

*`String` is internally backed by an array and can hold up tp Integer.MAX_VALUE characters (2^31-1)

If you do have enough heap memory for your process you can calculate like this:

- A char value in Java takes up 2 bytes of memory
- Every character of your base64 encoded file takes of two bytes internally
- base64 encoding makes 4 characters out of 3 bytes.

Apply some math and see if it fits or think hard and long why you need that data in memory in the first place.

Comment: yes, but whats is **approximately** the maximum size of the file that I can use...

Comment: That depends approximately on your memory... how much heap is assigned? How much will you need during copy?

Comment: my max heap size is 4'294'967'296  and my initial heap size is 268'435'456

Comment: So max heap = 2x maxint bytes = maxint chars in string  = 3/4 maxint bytes in base64 = somewhere around 1,5 gb file.