# Create a very long string and overcome runtime

Tags: java, string, time-complexity

*Can anyone help to reduce time to run this code?*

It's not an actual code, it's just a part of one of my project:

```
import java.util.*;

class testing{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="";

        for(long i=0L;i<10000000000L;i++)
            s+=String.valueOf(Character.toChars((int)(Math.random()*26+97)));

        System.out.println(s.length()+"\n"+s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a preallocated StringBuilder.

Comment: can you show me more precisely

Comment: Also this code will crash. Arrays have a max size of 2**31.

Comment: How about just replacing the string building with a bunch of `System.out.print` calls?

Comment: so there is no way to store this big string??

Comment: i want to create a random string @AndyTurner

Comment: @HarshVardhan why do you want to create such a string? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: If you want it that big, dump it to a stream... then it can be any size you want.

Comment: @AndyTurner just playing with string and pushing it to limits

Comment: Note that you can always create a more complex data-holder which stores the data in multiple objects. Much like `BigInteger` stores integers of arbitrary size using multiple `int`s.

Comment: You can't make a string that large. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41024966/3591528).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Instantiate  `StringBuilder` by setting the wished capacity :

```
 new StringBuilder(wishedSize)
```

2) You create a random `double` but you cast it to `int` :

```
(int)(Math.random()*26+97)
```

So you can use instead your own `Random` object before the loop and invoke `nextInt()`.

3) As Andy underlines (I didn't notice it) you get at the end a series of lower case letters.
You could use a `Random.nextInt(int)` to get a number between 97 and 122 (unicode range for small letters) such as :

```
final int maxRange = 122 - 97;
Random random = new Random();
for (long i = 0L; i < 100L; i++) {
    int codePoint = random.nextInt(maxRange) + 97;
    // ...
}
```

Besides, in this way you perform only 1 arithmetic computation on the returned random value instead of 2 of them previously.

Comment: 3) OP is creating a random string of lower case letters.

Comment: @Andy Turner Really nice to having seen that.

Answer (score 1):

You create a lot of Strings and concatenate them, which is quite slow.

Using a `StringBuilder` can be faster, if the expected size is known prior to generating the string:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(expectedStringLength);

for (int i = 0; i < expectedStringLength; i++)
    sb.append(Math.random() * 26 + 97);

System.out.println(sb.length() + "\n" + sb.toString());
```

Note however, that the length of the string cannot be bigger than `Interger.MAX_VALUE`, since it is backed by an array and java only supports `int` indices. Then again having such a big string will use a lot of memmory, so you might need to change your concept.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the crash, bypass the string entirely and dump it directly to filesystem.

```
try (OutputStream out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)), "utf-8") {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000L; i++) {
        out.write(Character.toChars((int)(Math.random()*26+97)));
    }
    out.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every string you make is immutable, so adding on to strings causes a lot of churn.  Use a buffer, like this

```
class testing{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(EST_SIZE);

    for(long i=0L;i<COUNT;i++)
        sb.append( Integer.toString(Math.random()*26+97 ) );

System.out.println(sb.length()+"\n"+sb.toString());
```

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.