# Cannot resolve symbol 'R' - too many strings?

Tags: android, string

I am working on a project which has a lot of strings. Some of my strings files are quite large having a thousand lines in some of them. This was fine until today when I tried to add more and everything stopped working.

When I tried to add more to one of my strings files suddenly all of my java files say 'Cannot resolve symbol R'. I remove the new strings and clean the project, and everything is back working again.

Is there a limit to the number of

```
<string name="string_name">words</string>
```

objects that I am allowed to have? Have I reached the limit? Please help.

Comment: Is your app running? Put those new strings and run it to check

Comment: I never faced this problem before but I doubt you hit the length limit there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have

Comment: The app is running fine before adding new strings. After adding the new strings, I get the 'Cannot resolve symbol R' error, and therefore the app will not compile and run anymore.

Comment: Have you tried assembleDebug ?

Comment: @Blue_Android What is that text which you are adding?

Comment: Just ordinary text, there are some '&' but I have already changed these to '&amp;'