# How to repeat a string n times in Kotlin, when n is Long

Tags: kotlin

I know using [repeat](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/repeat.html) function we can repeat a string n times but what if the n is bigger than a size of an `Int`

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible, unless long is actually small enough to fit in Int. String just can't contain so many characters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1179996/2956272

Comment: @dyukha, wow! never thought about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, though you are likely to run out of memory with such long strings

```
fun String.repeat(times: Long): String {
    val inner = (times / Integer.MAX_VALUE).toInt()
    val remainder = (times % Integer.MAX_VALUE).toInt()
    return buildString {
        repeat(inner) {
            append(this@repeat.repeat(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
        }
        append(this@repeat.repeat(remainder))
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't actually work (unless `times` fits into `Int` _or_ the string is empty), dyukha's comment is correct.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, Is there any other data type that can hold that amount of value other than `String`?

Comment: @AminMemariani Not in the standard library, unless I miss something. You can't even define your own implementing `CharSequence`, that has `int` length too.