# max file name length in Android

Tags: android

I am trying give a name for a file that I am creating.  I just want to know that
what is the max file name length in Android ?

Is there a specification for a file name? Can I use characters like `-` or `>` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

About the characters: Reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679699/what-characters-allowed-in-file-names-on-android), looks like `-` is not a reserved character, so it may be used. `>` however, is reserved therefore may not be used.

About the maximum length: Since I couldn't find anything specific to Android, and since java does not restrict the length of a file name it works with (As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512742/does-java-io-have-a-maximum-file-name-length)), I'd say the maximum length is like the most widely used limit, which is 255 bytes.

Comment: Does the extension enter in those 255 characters actually?

Comment: Yes, the extensions is considered to be a part of the path.

Comment: @Egor it's 127 characters limit, because 1 char is 2 bytes, so 127 chars is 254 bytes. Mel gave a very informative answer below.

Answer (score 27):

It is apparently unsafe to use labels over 127 bytes on Android. AFAIK, the 255 limit is a goal, but is a WIP. I trashed my Galaxy Tab 10.1's sdcard file system last week when music sync software generated some filenames of around 160 characters. Limiting the filenames to 127 solved the issue. Be safe, unless you are sure of your particular release... stick to a limit of 127.

Comment: 1 char = 2 bytes. Therefore it's 127 characters limit. :)

Comment: ASCII character is 1 byte right? How come it is 2 bytes?

Comment: @SamYC unicode character is 2 byte. Also some UTF8 encoding uses 1 or 2 bytes for a character

Comment: UTF-8 characters can be up to 4 bytes long. e.g.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding). When you say "unicode character is 2 byte", I assume you mean UCS-2 encodes a character in 2 bytes. Does this mean if e.g. your filename consists only of  characters it can be at most 63 characters long?

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case of resource names, like images, I've found that the max length is 100 characters, extension included. I've checked this in Android Studio 1.2 beta. I'm sure there must be something about this in the Android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that '-' (period) is a standard in naming as a rule. Frequently you will see special characters to create readability, such as the '.'  Yet, the period is a constant for separating the filename from the filetype nomenclature regardless of the OS. This rule goes back to the earliest days of computing. The thing that younger users do not realize is how rigid the rules were in those early years. Modern protocol, on the other hand makes more use of assumptions to shorten code so it takes less space. Just as your smartphone is smaller than an old IBM360, so too is modern instruction set.

Answer (score -2):

max file size in Android is

### 255