# FileNotFoundException : /storage/emulated/0/xyz/a bc/abc_06-07-2017 06-12-121481589883.amr

Tags: android, dropbox-api, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to upload file from my device storage to cloud but whenever I try to upload I am getting following excaption.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/xyz/a bc/abc_06-07-2017 06-12-121481589883.amr: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Here is my code.

```
        DropboxInstance objDropboxInstance = new DropboxInstance();
        String filePath = intent.getExtras().getString("filePath");
        // filePath is  = /storage/emulated/0/xyz/a bc/abc_06-07-2017 06-12-121481589883.amr
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        InputStream is;
        String name = "abc_06-07-2017 06-12-121481589883";
        try {
            File file = new File(filePath);           

            is = new FileInputStream(file);
            long size = f.length();
            objDropboxInstance.getDropBoxStorage(this).upload("/" + name, is, size, true);

        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I don't know what's happening. I think path is correct. But I am not getting why I am getting this error. Please suggest me.

Comment: Try shortening the filename and remove spaces from filepath.

Comment: @Ali Is there any limit for file name length?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498115/what-is-the-maximum-file-path-allowed-in-android

Comment: then file path length is not an issue..

Comment: did you try? It might work

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil are you using dropbox api v2?