# Bug in String.format / Formatter?

Tags: java, string, formatter

Out of curiosity I tried to create a really large string. It turned out that the [`Formatter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class chokes on width specifications exceeding `Integer.MAX_VALUE`:

```
// Produces an empty string. (2147483648 = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1)
String.format("%2147483648s", "");
```

So I went off to verify that it was indeed according to spec. But all it says is

> *If the format specifier contains a width or precision with an invalid value or which is otherwise unsupported, then a IllegalFormatWidthException or IllegalFormatPrecisionException respectively will be thrown.*

So in my opinion the correct behavior would be to throw an `IllegalFormatWidthException`.

Is this bug (?) documented somewhere? (If not, I'll go report it.)

---

Also, it should be noted that if one puts a `-` in front of the width (to left-justify the output):

```
String.format("%-2147483648s", "");
```

it indeed throws a `MissingFormatWidthException` (which, as I see it, seems to be correct behavior).

(I'm using OpenJDK version 1.6.0_20.)

Comment: You might be interested in this line in the summary, "Format String Syntax":  `The optional width is a non-negative decimal integer indicating the minimum number of characters to be written to the output.`  So at least we know it should be in the range of non-negative integers.

Comment: I think what might be happening is that it sees that there is an extremely large number for the width (or precision) that can't be parsed so it just ignores it.  It would be as if the format string was `"%s"` which is valid.  That would explain why having a negative throws the `MissingFormatWidthException`.  The negative only applies if there is a width specified.  If it was a very negative width, it would be as if the format string was `"%-s"` which is invalid.

Comment: Ah, good point, but no. `-((long) Integer.MAX_VALUE - 10)` still throws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right and that it's a bug: it should throw IllegalFormatWidthException, if any existing exception.

The javadoc for that exception says "Unchecked exception thrown when the format width is a negative value other than -1 or is otherwise unsupported", which oddly doesn't specifically mention values that are too large. I think the "otherwise unsupported" clause makes this a reasonable exception to throw.

Answer (score 1):

The format/formatter documentation should address this case, which is caused by trying to write a string to the format's appender that exceeds the maximum length of a string. If you actually needed to do this, you would have to use a stream.

See [String's Maximum length in Java - calling length() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816142/strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method)