# Data type for large amounts of text?

Tags: java, types

I'm developing a Java package that makes basic HTTP requests (GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE). Right now, I'm having it just print the output of the request. I would like to store it in a field, but I'm not sure if String supports large amounts of text. Is there a data type for large amounts of text, or is there a reasonable alternative to it? Right now, because I'm just printing it, I can't do anything with the data that is returned (like parse it, if it's JSON).

Any ideas would be helpful.

*Edit: The code is online [on GitHub](http://github.com/eturk/jack).*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String's Maximum length in Java - calling length() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816142/strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Strings can take up to 2^31 - 1 characters so I suspect are big enough. Data from [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816142/strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method)

Answer (score 3):

I see that you use `BufferedReader` in your code. You can just leave the string in there and pass that reader to your JSON parser for instance. Would be more efficient than first creating a String out of it.

Comment: I need to return it as a string if it isn't JSON, so I need to make a String out of it anyways. Thanks for the tip, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing a single set of operations on the data, you can stream it through a pipeline and not even store the entire data in memory at any time. It can also boost performance as work can begin upon the first character rather than after the last is received. Check out CharSequence.