# Java, jboss, mysql, jdbc : string max lenght ?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jboss

Is there a limitation to the maximum size of string between java, jdbc, jboss and mysql?

I have a string that gets stuck to 33000 characters? Maybe a configuration somewhere?

Comment: What is the datatype in MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

The string can run into other OS specific limitations before you can achieve a maximum length of the string.

Typically you can declare varchar as type in mysql with defined column lengths.

Also you can define blob types for storing really large binary objects in databases, most databases support the varchar and blob types.

With respect to JDBC you have the support to persist the data, that should not be a problem and I dont see a problem with JBOSS as well.

For max length of string please see

[String's Maximum length in Java - calling length() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816142/strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method)

Can you add more details to your question, if the above does not answer.