# jawampa maximum websockt frame size?

Tags: java, netty, wamp-protocol

Is there a maximum size for the arguments when publishing an event?

I use this code (java): `wampClient.publish(token, response.toString());`

`response.toString()` is a long json-string in my case. It has about 70.000 characters. I have the suspicion that the event does not get published, because when I replace `response.toString()` with a short string, the event gets published as expected.

I dont know much about the internals of Wamp and an initial debugging session into the code did not provide me with much insight. As I said above, I think that the long string is causing some problems.

**Minimal running example:** To get a minimum running example, please download the example java project from here: http://we.tl/a3kj3dzJ7N and import it into your IDE.

In the demo folder there are two .java-files: `Client.java` and `Server.java`
Run/Start both of them and a GUI should appear for each. Then do the following procedure (C = Client, S = Server):

```
C: hit start
S: hit start
C: hit publish
```

depending on the size of the message you will see different output on the console of your IDE. the size of the message can be changed in *line 137* of `Client.java` via the `size` integer variable. As already explained above: If `size` is lower than 70000 (e.g. 60000) everything works as expected. The console output of `Client.java` is then as follows:

```
Open Client
Session1 status changed to Connecting
Session1 status changed to Connected
Publishing
Received event test.event with value 10000
```

However, if the integer variable `size` is changed to 70000 (or higher) the output is as follows:

```
Open Client
Session1 status changed to Connecting
Session1 status changed to Connected
Publishing
Completed event test.event
Session1 status changed to Disconnected
Session1 status changed to Connecting
Session1 status changed to Connected
```

As you can see the *Received event ...* is missing, hence, the event is not received. However, there is *Completed event test.event*, but the data is missing obviously.

To sum up, one can see when running the example above that the event is not received properly when the size of the transmitted string is greater than 70000. This problem may be related to *netty* since it is used under the hood of *jawampa*. Any help is appreciated. Maybe it's just some small configuration which can fix this problem.

**EDIT 1:** I updated the question with a minimal running example which can be downloaded.

**EDIT 2:** I think I now know the root of the problem (totally not sure though, see EDIT3). It is related to the allowed size of a string literal in java. See: [Size of Initialisation string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323082/size-of-initialisation-string-in-java/8323747#8323747)
In the above example, I can reflect that. If the size variable is lower than 65535 characters, it works, else it doesnt. Is there a workaround for this?

**EDIT 3 aka SOLUTION:** As suggested by the developer (see [here](https://github.com/Matthias247/jawampa/issues/67#issuecomment-134939556)), the variable `DEFAULT_MAX_FRAME_PAYLOAD_LENGTH` in [NettyWampConnectionConfig.java:8](https://github.com/Matthias247/jawampa/blob/698afa808ab6b2603fe926eef758556d6db2b2b5/jawampa-netty/src/main/java/ws/wamp/jawampa/transport/netty/NettyWampConnectionConfig.java#L8) should be changed to a higher value. then everything works like a charm.

Comment: Which api are you using?

Comment: [jawampa](https://github.com/Matthias247/jawampa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by the developer (see [here](https://github.com/Matthias247/jawampa/issues/67#issuecomment-134939556)), the variable `DEFAULT_MAX_FRAME_PAYLOAD_LENGTH` can be overwritten through the `NettyWampConnectionConfig` class, which you can provide to the `NettyWampClientConnectorProvider` class. The variable value should, obviously, be increased.

Comment: Actually i disagree with accepted answer, because first of all, you should avoid editing base package. Instead `DEFAULT_MAX_FRAME_PAYLOAD_LENGTH`could be changed using builder: 

    .withConnectionConfiguration((new NettyWampConnectionConfig.Builder()).withMaxFramePayloadLength(2147483648).build())

Answer (score 0):

There is bug in jawampa, cause `DEFAULT_MAX_FRAME_PAYLOAD_LENGTH` is 1 bite lower than default split frame size in Crossbar. So `DEFAULT_MAX_FRAME_PAYLOAD_LENGTH` should be increased just by 1 bite or crossbar split frame size should be lowered by 1.
Also if you change `DEFAULT_MAX_FRAME_PAYLOAD_LENGTH`, it should be changed using builder: `.withConnectionConfiguration((new NettyWampConnectionConfig.Builder()).withMaxFramePayloadLength(65536).build())`