# JSP When to use empty scriptlet tags

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, scriptlet

Often when developing, I come across the following: -

`<%%>`

Totally empty scriptlet tags.

In the past, removing this "mere nuisance" polluting the codebase has caused my JSP's not to work.

- **What is the purpose of these empty scriptlet tags?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately JSP pages are compiled to `.java` files which compile to `.class` files.

I seem to remember that literal strings in a `.java` file have a maximum size limit. I'm guessing that `<%%>` was added to the middle of a very long piece of static html in the JSP to force two or more string literals in the resultant `.java` file.

It might be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323082/size-of-initialisation-string-in-java) which suggests:

> The value of the code_length item must be less than 65536.