# Is there any limit for string size in a Java program?

Tags: java, string, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String's Maximum length in Java - calling length() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816142/strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method)

I have a string defined as

String xx

Is there any limit for the number of characters that I can assign?

2) I am assigning the user input to this string xx.
70% of the times people give only one word. some times they give a big sentence so want to know is that ok? or is there any better  java practices?

Comment: Did you even briefly Google this before posting? The second hit for `java string length limit` was the duplicate listed above.

Comment: If you have to ask, you're already doing the wrong thing. Strings shouldn't be treated as containers.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A common question you could have searched for but I going to answer it again anyway.

> Is there any limit for the number of characters that I can assign?

Its Integer.MAX_VALUE or 2^31-1 or about 2 billion.  You are more likely to have memory problems before getting to this size. e.g. You need 4 GB for the String and 4 GB to create it.

> I am assigning the user input to this string xx. 70% of the times people give only one word. some times they give a big sentence so want to know is that ok?

I suspect all the works of J K Rowling would fit into one string.

> or is there any better java practices?

I suggest you keep things as simple as possible. Assigning a String reference is about simple as it gets.

Comment: Keep in mind that if the heap size, divided by the size of `char` (which is 2), is smaller than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, that will be the upper bound instead.

Comment: @Eric So "much more than a sentence" .. ;-)

Comment: @Eric True, as I mentioned you need 4 bytes for every char you want in the strings. (2 bytes for the String and 2 bytes to build it)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ah, yes, I didn't realize where you had pulled these numbers from. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: And you need a **contiguous heap segment** for each of those 4GB blocks, so even an 8GB heap may not cut it.

Comment: The CMS collector doesn't de-fragment memory so you can get this problem.

Comment: congrats, your answer is now the top google search result. so most people who find this answer actually did search for it!