# In java String is a class then how it has limited size allocation

Tags: java, string, class

I know string enjoyed some privilege and it is defined as class in java.
As reference to that post [Is there any limit for string size in a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120002/is-there-any-limit-for-string-size-in-a-java-program) String has a size of around 2^31-1.So my question is that how a class has limited size allocation because as i know a class can allocate as many memory blocks as it is required

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816142/strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, the `String` class contains an array of characters (`char[]`), which actually is the content the `String` instance represents.

Java is designed [(and often criticized)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Java#Large_arrays) in such way so that it does not support arrays of size more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (which is exactly 2<sup>31</sup> - 1).

So, to summarize, the limit of the size of internal `char[]` array is actually the limit of the size of the `String`.

Comment: So even though String is a class but it is implemented in same as a c style internally,and it can be crashed if size of string is greater than 2^31-1

Comment: Seems so, yes. You can try it out, if you wish - you'd get an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Another food for thought could be the question - Why one would maintain a `String` that could be so huge, instead of implementing a data structure that can replace the single `String`? :)

Comment: and it is the double in bytes: char=2bytes - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699071/what-is-the-javas-internal-represention-for-string-modified-utf-8-utf-16