# string size more than max limit of int

Tags: java, string, string-length

I have a huge set of strings, where I want to find the length of the each string and add them and display the total length of string.

To calculate the length, I use method as `string.length()`, but I noticed that datatype of length() is int and max size of int is 2,147,483,647. However my string object have characters more then 2,147,483,647. Any suggestion how to get the length when it goes beyond int limit?

Comment: Where are your strings stored?

Comment: Just for curiosity: What string objects have more characters than 2^31 ?! This is enough for 2000 books of 500 pages with DIN A4 format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However my string object have characters more then 2,147,483,647

I doubt it: a String uses a `char[]` to store the characters and arrays can't hold more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816142/strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method).

If you simply need to add the lengths of several strings, you can use a long variable instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a string longer than that.

[`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) is the upper limit for indexing the internal character arrays used to store your string objects, so there isn't a way for you to have strings longer than that.

Comment: In Java size of Integer does not vary with underlying system.

Comment: @FabianBarney I changed that to say JVM. The bit-ness of the JVM does matter does it not?

Comment: Here is a blog post that describes the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit JVM storage of strings.  http://lingpipe-blog.com/2010/06/22/the-unbearable-heaviness-jav-strings/

Comment: No, it does not. Integers are always 32-Bit in Java and C#.

Comment: @FabianBarney & Richard Chambers Thanks. I need to get my basics straight :)

Answer (score 1):

In java no string object can have length greater than  `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so string.length will work for you, but if you want have overall length of set of string greater than   `Integer.MAX_VALUE` than you can use long type variable to store the value of length of overall set of strings

Comment: That will not make a difference. Since `String.length` returns an `int`. So, before typecasting, the data would already have been truncated.

Comment: you have set of strings, and each element can return the length greater than int in java, so there will be no truncation but when you are adding the different element length store that in long type and that method should use long type as return type

Comment: Can't understand your first statement. Why there will be no truncation in case your length is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: You cant have any string that has length greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE in java

Comment: Exactly. And in that case, your answer makes absolutely no sense. Please update it.

Comment: My answer is about how you should get overall length for all string

Comment: Then also it doesn't answer the question. OP is concerned that his strings are greater in length than and int can afford. Please re-read the question.

Comment: @RohitJain It makes sense what zaffar says. Since Java Strings cannot hold more than Integer.MAX_VALUE characters but it seems that the OP likes to deal with these large strings, it makes sense to tell him that he can work witha bunch of strings instead and calculate overall length using the long type. Do not want to say to recommend something like that but it makes sense in this context here.

Comment: @FabianBarney. Well, the answer now makes sense, after he edited it. :)

Comment: @FabianBarney , Rohit is right :) it realy make sense after editing , Thanks Rohit :)