# Maximum size of content that JTextPane can hold?

Tags: java, swing, document, jtextpane, text-size

I would like to know the maximum size of data that a JTextPane could hold. This is needed as I am unable to retrieve the entire contents of a JTextPane , for writing out to a file , in an application at my office.

In that application I generate XML based on some business logic , load it into a JTextPane and  upon validation of the same , write it out to the disk.

I'm losing a part of the JTextPane contents ( the data that is to be written out)  on creating a File object for this purpose.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What kind of limits are you looking for? Why does it matter to you?

Comment: Do you mean before you run out of memory, or before its performance becomes unusable to an end-user ? And have you already tried adding heaps of text to it ?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I wish to save the contents of a JTextPane to a file. But I am unable to save the entire file , only a small section of it. Thats why the question.

Comment: @Robin The MAXIMUM number of characters I can retrieve from a JTextPane at any time using the getText() method.

Comment: @Abe Then your question should probably be about how to save textpane content to a file. In that case, consider providing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) illustrating what you have done so far.

Comment: Consider using the `write()` method iso using `getText()` for writing to file. And note that your question very poorly reflects what you actually try to achieve and where you encounter problems. Consider updating it

Comment: _But I am unable to save the entire file , only a small section of it._ Most likely you are doing something wrong and it is unlikely a question of limits.

Comment: *"..how much data can a JTextPane hold at one time ?"*  More than a user can handle or even effectively navigate.  Easily the Old Testament (yes, all of it), for e.g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably be retrieving the contents of the `JTextPane` as a `String` at some point which means that you'll have a technical upper limit of just over 2 billion characters (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816142/strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method)). Having said that the application will become totally unresponsive long before you get anywhere close to that number of characters.

As for saving the contents to a file you shouldn't have any problems writing out that much data assuming you have a couple of GB of free disk space. If you need an example of writing a file have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-and-write-to-a-file).

It is possible that you are losing the end of the data because you aren't closing the stream when you are finished with it or you are using a buffer and failing to flush it correctly after the last write.