# Is there efficient way to convert org.json.JSONObject to POJO model using GSON?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Is there efficient way to convert org.json.JSONObject to POJO model using GSON ?
(At the moment U thought to do like

```
Gson g=new Gson();
g.fromJson(json.toString(), PersonModel.class);
```

`json is JSONObject`).
I am using volley and in response I get instance of JSONObject  and I can parse like on http://www.kpbird.com/2013/05/volley-easy-fast-networking-for-android.html but I have complex structure in models like nested lists and I would like to avoid manual extracting of data from json.

Comment: Is the snippet you posted failing?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't think so, I just think that there is maybe size cosntaring for String in Java so if object is big I can be in problem ( If I can convert JSONObject to stream)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816142/strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method for maximum string length. If you are  on a phone and processing an object graph that turns into a 2GB String then I suspect you will have bigger problems earlier in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

First, sorry for bumping an old question.

I was asking myself this same question and found this example in the Android Volley section called [implementing custom requests](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html) in the Android Developer site.

```
@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(
        NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String json = new String(response.data,
        HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
    return Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }
    // handle errors
...
}
```

I would just use the StringRequest and use GSON on the response callback, it should be faster than getting a JSONObject and converting it to String prior to calling GSON. For what I see in the JSONObject javadoc there's no way to create an instance from a byte[], so probably the HTTP response in bytes is converted to String, then to JSONObject, and then you convert it to String again. By using StringRequest we can skip the last 2 steps.