# Is there a max value for versioncode?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

We always have to increment `versionCode` by some arbitary number to publish it to google play.
Is there limit to that value and what will happen if it is reached?

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 65
        versionName "1.05"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "myapp-$versionCode")

    }
```

Comment: it is an integer (32bit) - accordingly to the documentation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum Length of Android versionName / versionCode (Manifest)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246143/maximum-length-of-android-versionname-versioncode-manifest)

Comment: The question is what happens after you reached that maximum?

Comment: you will not be able update app)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Update 08/11/2016 (UTC):

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html) has been updated. Not the old `MAX_INT` value nor the 2000000000.

> Warning: The greatest value Google Play allows for `versionCode` is **2100000000**.

---

Cross-post for visibility here.

It seems there was a recent change in Google, making the maximum `versionCode` up to 2000000000 only.

Reference post: [Google Play Developer Console error: The version code of your APK is high and you risk not being able to update your APK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38481212/4625829)

---

PS: For those who are planning to provide reference to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html) where the mentioned max value is 2147483647, please read the answer first in the post I referenced. It mentions that as of current date (08/10/2016), its still not updated.

Comment: This makes no sense as the given number is about `150 000` smaller than `MAX_INT`.

Comment: @xenteros Have you tried updating an app with a `versionCode` higher than that value? Test it out. If you were able to, I'd remove this answer.

Comment: I imagine this number was chosen because it allows dated versions 20190313xx. 100 builds per day until 2100 should be enough.

Comment: @NunoCruces fair point, though 2147483647 also does that. The only thing I can think of is that 2147483647 is less memorable!

Answer (score 18):

According to [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html) and the gradle [DSL documentation](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor:versionCode):

`android:versionCode` — An `integer` value that represents the version of the application code, relative to other versions.

Checking the java doc, by default, the `int` data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of (2^31)-1.

Then the maximum value is **2^31-1.**

Comment: Here is the doc  of the Android Gradle DSL - link http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor:versionCode

Comment: That doesn't help you at all though, if you want to publish your app on the Google Play Store which only accepts a certain amount of version numbers.

Answer (score 9):

Starting at Android Pie (9), the version code will be a `long` ([source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#getLongVersionCode())). The max value of a `long` is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` so you shouldn't run into any issues regarding length here.

Do note that it's still an `int` in older android versions, so `long` is only relevant to you when your `minSdkVersion` is 28 or higher.

Comment: versionCode (publicly facing, play store visible versionCode) will remain a 32-bit int. The "longVersionCode" referred to here is a bit mask of this 32-bit versionCode in the lower bits and the manifest value "versionCodeMajor" in the upper 32-bits. versionCodeMajor Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifest_versionCodeMajor

Comment: That doesn't help you at all though, if you want to publish your app on the Google Play Store which only accepts a certain amount of version numbers.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought the version code was supposed to encode things like ABI, so that, for example, a device that supports arm 64 bit and 32 bit, will get the 64 bit libs as priority. But the docs now indicate that when uploading multiple APKs (e.g. split by ABI) they should have same versionCode.

Comment: The whole API doesn't make sense imo. Hiding the version code bit shifting behind a very misleading method name feels like someone really wanted to screw other developers. This is not what ANYONE would expect, especially when the int versions of the according getter and setter are actually deprecated... Why you cant use long in 2018+ (Android API 28 release) is beyond me. Why anyone decided to use a int in the first place even more.

Answer (score 9):

The other responses are technically true but you should note that [Google Play Store only accepts version codes up to 2100000000](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning).