# How to create the android VERSION_CODE automatic?

Tags: android, svn, android-gradle-plugin, release

I'm working in an enterprise development environment. Actually we are setting the android VERSION_CODE and VERSION_NAME manually, but this got us some conflicts with the version code.

The scheme of the version name is x.x.x[.x] so it might be 3.1.3 or 3.1.3.2

In dev we automatically increase the version_code every local build via gradle script. But this number grows to fast and is not transferable between versions, branches and developers.

We use svn as vcs and only one branch per version. One solution approach is to multiply the version name by factors to get an increasing number (min 100 place per field. But we got to high(see [max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275071/is-there-a-max-value-for-versioncode)). e.g.:

```
1.2.3.4.svn-version(5678)
| | | | |----           1
| | | |------       10000
| | |--------     1000000
| |----------   100000000
|------------ 10000000000

example:  10.203.045.678
max-code: 2.100.000.000
```

Is there a way to increase the local version code each build but keep the number in line in multiple releases with multiple developers? How to use svn-version, branch name or something else for this purpose?