# Bigger data type than String

Tags: java, android

The POST Message response that is returned from the server to my Android app is an essay. The String datatype unfortunately cannot store the entire essay.

Can you suggest a data-type i can use like this:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

String result = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
```

when i `System.out.println(result)` it doesn't show me the entire essay.

Comment: Two strings? Or maybe three?

Comment: What is the actual limitation you are seeing, in Java? In your database? From [what I am reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have) an essay should not go over the max amount of characters a string can hold.  However, you may want to look at your heap size according to that post I linked

Comment: You should be able to get a string of max length java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE which is 2147483647 or (2^31 - 1). Is your string is of greater length than this?

Comment: How can i detect when the string becomes full

Comment: a string is full from what both Srikanth Ganji and I said, at (2^31 -1) characters long.  Or at half your maximum heap size.

Comment: See [how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have) and [strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816142/strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method)

Comment: I very, *very* much doubt that the problem is actually that the value is larger than the theoretical capabilities of `String`. You may be running out of memory, but that's a different matter. Unfortunately, you haven't described the actual failure.

Comment: when i System.out.println(result) it doesnot display the entire essay

Comment: That doesn't mean that result doesn't have the data, just that you're having an issue printing it.  Compare `result.length()` to the length of the essay on the server.

Comment: @user3760741 That's a limitation of `System.out.println` on your JVM, not of the `String` type.

Comment: If the server is from your own development, you may want to consider some other way of storing and transmitting essays. Binary or XML.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think that this is `String` size problem.

Eg.

An A4 page covered with characters stores about 5000 characters. Acording to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179983/how-many-characters-can-a-java-string-have), the maximum length of `String` is 2147483647 characters.

```
2147483647/5000 = 429496 pages
```

The Encyclopædia Britannica has 32640 pages and about 44000000 words with average 6.1 characters per word.

Why are you trying to send 8 Encyclopædias?

Comment: Lol..i am not. I get it..There is a limitation of `System.out.println`

Comment: Do people still use that weird letter made of a and e mashed together?