# UTF8 representation for string * is too long for the constant pool

Tags: java, string, utf-8

I have a `String`, which is then converted into an JSON-object:

```
public static final String JSON_STRING = "json string";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
```

But sometimes when the `String` is too long, I get the error:

> UTF8 representation for string * is too long for the constant pool

Are there other ways to get a such long string?

Comment: Put the data in a file and read from there instead. It is an issue with your adding a too large string literal in the source code.

Comment: Create several strings and concatenate them in the static initializer?

Answer (score 4):

Strings are stored in [class file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7) in UTF-8 and the limit is 65535 bytes.
String constructed in runtime can be [much longer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816142/strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method)

So you should either split your string constant on multiple string constants and concatenate them before use or read the value from text file.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the JVM (specifically, the classfile format) puts a limit of 65535 characters.

From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11):

> The length of field and method names, field and method descriptors,
>   and other constant string values (including those referenced by
>   ConstantValue (§4.7.2) attributes) is limited to 65535 characters by
>   the 16-bit unsigned length item of the CONSTANT_Utf8_info structure
>   (§4.4.7).