# Accessing characters of a String beyond the range of Integer

Tags: java, string, primitive-types

I have a `String/character` sequence that is being repeated infinitesimally... Naturally ,characters will go out of range of Integer and start falling into range of Long, since methods used for accessing characters  for both String as well as `StringBuilder` class all require an `int "index"` how do I access these characters at say ,`Long long>Intger.MAX_VALUE`  . is there a way to override these methods such as `charAt(int index)` so that they start "accepting " long arguments ,if not so , how can I access the characters at this index, considered conversion to character array using `String.toCharArray()` method but then again, array length can only be upto `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Is there a `method/constructor` type that I'm not aware of which accepts long arguments?

Comment: the maximum length of a String is Integer.MAX_VALUE, afaik. There won't be any characters beyond that range

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String's Maximum length in Java - calling length() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816142/strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method)

Comment: i cross checked .. you are correct ,Shouldve checked myself before asking,need to make modifications accordingly!

Comment: A string consists of a character array and some additional information. Your string is completely theoretical. You have not created it, and you wouldn't be able to. Perhaps you should refer us to the actual problem that you think will require such a string.

Comment: @RealSkeptic  Ok , So the problem is like is This                                                       Lilah has a string,s , of lowercase English letters that she repeated infinitely many times.

Given an integer,n , find and print the number of letter a's in the first  letters of Lilah's infinite string.                                                                       Sample Input                                                                                           a
1000000000000

Comment: So you need to figure out what the repeated String `s` is, figure out how many "a"s there are in it, and how many times her String would fit into 1000000000000 characters. **This doesn't mean you have to actually construct a 1000000000000-char String!** It's a glorified math problem, not a String-management problem.

Comment: Is this the Philoshophical Programming forum?

Comment: yes , i understood how i need to handle this case and similar to it ,in a different manner an its just ludicrous to construct such a string!

Comment: But my point is, you don't have to construct the string, and probably shouldn't even consider it. Look, if the repeated String were "CaliforniaDreamin", that's 17 characters, so in the first 1000000000000 characters it repeats 58823529411 times, and then there are the first 13 characters again ("CalforniaDre"). So the number of "a"s here is 3 for each full repeat, and 2 for the partial at the end. 3*58823529411 + 2 = 176470588235.

Comment: Got it, Fresh perspective1 I just have to perform calculations based on the numbers provided! so its just like a math problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely not construct a string and do measurements on it.

This is a test on how well you are able to abstract things. I will give you some code you may study. You should not copy+paste it for several reasons - including the possibility that I did some mistake.

The idea is, to simply compute the information, which is possible because we have a simple repetition pattern.

```
class RepeatedString {
    private String s;
    public RepeatedString(String s) {this.s = s;}

    public char charAt(long i) {
      return s.charAt((int)(i % s.length()));
    }

    public long count(char c, long i) {
      long n = 0;
      // how many complete repetitions?
      {
        long r = i / s.length();
        if (r > 0) {
          // count c in s
          for (int j = 0 ; j < s.length() ; j++) n += s.charAt(j) == c ? 1 : 0;
          n *= r;
        }
      }
      // how many c in last repitition
      {
        long l = i % s.length();
        for (int j = 0 ; j < l ; j++) n += s.charAt(j) == c ? 1 : 0;
      }
      return n;
    }
}

class Kata {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RepeatedString s = new RepeatedString("bla");

    System.out.println(s.charAt(1)); // expected 'l'
    System.out.println(s.charAt(6)); // expected 'b'

    System.out.println(s.count('a', 19)); // expected 6
    System.out.println(s.count('a', 21)); // expected 7
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, the Comments section above gave me a fresh perspective towards this problem, and your code cemented that concept for me.. Of course, i will not be copy pasting this code ,since i might want to apply the same logic with a slightly different approach, but it was really helpful to get me familiar with the direction in which i should be thinking about this problem and any future problems i encounter with a similar pattern to it!