# Efficient way match a regex Pattern on an OutputStream greater than max String limit

Tags: java, string, outputstream

I am trying to find an efficient way to do a pattern match on a ByteArrayOutputStream whose size exceeds [String's max size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/816152/10639803).

Doing a pattern match on a ByteArrayOutputStream that fits into a single String is trivial:

```
private boolean doesStreamContainPattern(Pattern pattern, ByteArrayOutputStream baos) throws IOException {

    /*
     *  Append external source String to output stream...
     */

    if (pattern != null) {
        String out = new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
        if (pattern.matcher(out).matches()) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Some other processing if no pattern match
     */
    return false;
}
```

But if the size of `baos` exceeds String max size, the problem turns into:

1. Feeding `baos` into multiple Strings.
2. "Sliding" the pattern matching over the concatenation of those multiple Strings (i.e. the original `baos` content).

Step 2 looks more challenging then Step 1 but I know that utilities like Unix [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) do just that on a file.

What is the right way to accomplish that?

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense to match against an `OutputStream`, no? You're not writing to the stream, you're reading it - so it should be an `InputStream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple wrapper class to implement `CharSequence` from the stream:

```
class ByteArrayCharSequence implement CharSequence {
    private byte[] array;
    public StreamCharSequence(byte[] input) {
        array = input;
    }

    public char charAt(int index) {
        return (char) array[index];
    }
    public int length() {
        return array.length;
    }
    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        return new ByteArrayCharSequence(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, start, end));
    }
    public String toString() {
        // maybe test whether we exceeded max String length
    }
}
```

and then match by

```
private boolean doesStreamContainPattern(Pattern pattern, ByteArrayOutputStream baos) throws IOException {
    if (pattern != null) {
        CharSequence seq = new ByteArrayCharSequence(baos.toByteArray());
        if (pattern.matcher(seq).matches()) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Some other processing if no pattern match
     */
    return false;
}
```

It's obviously rough around the edges with the cast to `char`, and using `copyOfRange`, but it should work for most cases and you can adjust for those where it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for your help. Please note that your solution is also limited by the inherent size/length limit of CharSequence (Integer.MAX_VALUE). I now believe the solution should be more in the direction of using [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) along with [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)

Comment: Well, `Integer.MAX_VALUE` can address up to 2 GB of data, but I guess either way, `Scanner` is a good idea. You'll find it accepts an `InputStream` rather than an `OutputStream`, as I pointed out makes more sense in my previous comment to the question.